# Empirical Bayes Estimation: Different transformation, fully different results

Tags: bayesian, binomial-distribution, regularization, ratio, empirical-bayes

I would be grateful for some advice regarding the following problems:

As I reviewed some empirical papers, I learned that most of them use a relatively small number of observations for performing Empirical Bayes estimation.

Question 1: Can I use it with bigger data sets?

Question 2: I am using two different types of arcsin transformations.

My use case is the following: I report firm-level statistics for a large universe of firms, large and small, where for privacy reasons each individual had only a 50% chance of being observed. I want to shrink the firm-level ratios both for small-firm estimates being noisy but also because we are not observing ground truth in any case. The James-Stein estimator after a non-linear transformation was a natural fit for our case.

Let me review equations 7.12, 7.13, 7.21, and 7.23 from [Efron and Hastie](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/CASI_files/PDF/casi.pdf) and information from slides 6-7 in this presentation from [Ignatiadis and Wager](https://nignatiadis.github.io/assets/talks/neurips_2019_covariate_ebayes.pdf).

I performed the transformation and finished the procedure but got different results. 
When I used the method from Efron and Hastie some fractions became negative (outside the 0-1 interval) but always positive using the method from Ignatiadis and [Wager](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/24498/stefan-wager). Is this reasonable for such similar procedures?

**Equations from Efron and Hastie:**
[image]
[image: s]
Transform back:
[image]

**Equations from Ignatiadis and Wagner:**

[image]

And here We have to transform back as well.
[image]

Why do I get so different results?

Comment: Concerning your first questions. From my limited understanding, [empirical Bayes estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_Bayes_method) constructs the prior using information from the data. There is no issue with sample size there I think. Seems like a method even closer to maximum likelihood estimation than normal Bayesian inference with (relatively) large sample size.

Comment: Maybe one for @Stefan Wager?